# What amount of bookshelves and experience levels is required for which enchantments?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I am kind of looking for a list of them like for instance how many bookshelves and experience is required for luck of the sea to be available, i know the silk touch enchantment requires 30 levels and 15 bookshelves, can someone give me a list with this kind of data on enchantments?

Comment: Did you check the pages about enchantment on Minecraft Wiki?

Comment: Yes, but it didn't give me exactly what i'm looking for, there isn't a chart with info like unbreaking 1 requires this many bookshelves and this many xp levels, silk touch requires this many bookshelves and this many xp levels, and etc.

Comment: Well, you can compile that table from the information on that page with a bit of math.  It is just that no one thought of making a table like that ...

Comment: .......not to be rude, least helpful....sorry......i should just.....yeah........

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Enchantment mechanics on the wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Enchanting_mechanics#Basic_mechanics):

| Number of Bookshelves | Level range of top slot | Level range of middle slot | Level range of bottom slot |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1–2 | 1–6 | 1–8 |
| 1 | 1–3 | 1–7 | 2–9 |
| 2 | 1–3 | 2–8 | 4–11 |
| 3 | 1–4 | 2–9 | 6–12 |
| 4 | 1–4 | 3–10 | 8–14 |
| 5 | 1–5 | 3–11 | 10–15 |
| 6 | 1–5 | 3–12 | 12–17 |
| 7 | 1–6 | 3–13 | 14–18 |
| 8 | 1–6 | 4–14 | 16–20 |
| 9 | 1–7 | 4–15 | 18–21 |
| 10 | 2–7 | 5–16 | 20–23 |
| 11 | 2–8 | 5–17 | 22–24 |
| 12 | 2–8 | 5–18 | 24–26 |
| 13 | 2–9 | 5–19 | 26–27 |
| 14 | 2–9 | 6–20 | 28–29 |
| 15 | 2–10 | 6–21 | 30 |

This base enchantment level is modified using 2 modifiers:

1. A random integer is generated between 0 and half the enchantability of the item (see the table below). This number + 1 is added to the base enchantment level.

| Material | Armour Enchantability | Sword/Tool Enchantability |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Wood | N/A | 15 |
| Leather | 15 | N/A |
| Stone | N/A | 5 |
| Chain | 12 | N/A |
| Iron | 9 | 14 |
| Gold | 25 | 22 |
| Diamond | 10 | 10 |
| Turtle | 9 | N/A |
| Netherite | 15 | 15 |
| Book | 1 | 1 |

Bows and fishing rods also have an enchantability of 1

2. A random number is chosen between 0.85 and 1.15. This is multiplied to the modified level from step 1. This means that the modified level can increase or decrease by up to 15%.

On [Enchanting/Levels](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Enchanting/Levels) ([permalink](https://minecraft.wiki/w/index.php?title=Enchanting/Levels&oldid=1422633)) there is a list of the modified enchantment level ranges for each enchantment (<s>excluding crossbows</s> Edit: crossbow enchantments have been added). If the modified enchantment level is in two ranges for the same enchantment type (e.g. Fortune I and Fortune II), the higher one is used.

---

## Edit

> i know that the silk touch enchantment requires 30 levels and 15 bookshelves

I assume by "require" you mean that there is a 100% chance that the game may pick an enchantment after the modified enchantment level has been calculated.

For example, to find the number of bookshelves and levels needed to get Silk Touch on a diamond pickaxe you would have to work backwards.

1. The modified enchantment level for Silk Touch is 15–65.
2. To guarantee that there will be a chance of getting Silk Touch, use the worst-case scenario: the modified level after step 1 would be reduced by 15%, meaning that this level would need to be at least 15 ÷ 0.85 = 18 (rounded to the nearest integer).
3. A diamond pickaxe's enchantability is 10 (this actually isn't needed to calculate a guaranteed number of bookshelves).
4. The worst-case scenario will be that in the first modifier, 0 will be chosen (from 0 to half the enchantability). This number + 1 will be added to the base enchantment level, meaning that the **base enchantment level will be 18 - 0 - 1 = 17**.
5. Looking at the first table, it can be seen that **at least 9 bookshelves are required to get Silk Touch in at least the third slot** (the number of bookshelves where all the possible levels will be greater than or equal to 17). I also found that the number of bookshelves is the base enchantment level ÷ 2 rounded up.

#### TLDR: The number of levels required is (lowest modified enchantment level for enchantment) ÷ 0.85 - 1. The number of bookshelves is the number of levels ÷ 2 rounded down.

---

Here's info on the number of bookshelves and levels required for each enchantment:

| Enchantment | Levels | Bookshelves |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Aqua Affinity I | 0 | 0 |
| Bane of Arthropods I | 5 | 3 |
| Bane of Arthropods II | 14 | 7 |
| Bane of Arthropods III | 24 | 12 |
| Bane of Arthropods IV | 33 | 17 |
| Bane of Arthropods V | 43 | 22 |
| Blast Protection I | 5 | 3 |
| Blast Protection II | 14 | 7 |
| Blast Protection III | 24 | 12 |
| Blast Protection IV | 33 | 17 |
| Channeling I | 28 | 14 |
| Depth Strider I | 11 | 6 |
| Depth Strider II | 23 | 12 |
| Depth Strider III | 34 | 17 |
| Efficiency I | 0 | 0 |
| Efficiency II | 12 | 6 |
| Efficiency III | 24 | 12 |
| Efficiency IV | 35 | 18 |
| Efficiency V | 47 | 24 |
| Feather Falling I | 5 | 3 |
| Feather Falling II | 12 | 6 |
| Feather Falling III | 19 | 10 |
| Feather Falling IV | 26 | 13 |
| Fire Aspect I | 11 | 6 |
| Fire Aspect II | 34 | 17 |
| Flame I | 23 | 12 |
| Fortune I | 17 | 9 |
| Fortune II | 27 | 14 |
| Fortune III | 38 | 19 |
| Frost Walker I | 11 | 6 |
| Frost Walker II | 23 | 12 |
| Impaling I | 0 | 0 |
| Impaling II | 10 | 5 |
| Impaling III | 19 | 10 |
| Impaling IV | 28 | 14 |
| Impaling V | 38 | 19 |
| Infinity I | 23 | 12 |
| Knockback I | 5 | 3 |
| Knockback II | 28 | 14 |
| Looting I | 5 | 3 |
| Looting II | 27 | 14 |
| Looting III | 38 | 19 |
| Loyalty I | 19 | 10 |
| Loyalty II | 25 | 13 |
| Loyalty III | 31 | 16 |
| Luck of the Sea I | 17 | 9 |
| Luck of the Sea II | 27 | 14 |
| Luck of the Sea III | 38 | 19 |
| Lure I | 17 | 9 |
| Lure II | 27 | 14 |
| Lure III | 38 | 19 |
| Multishot I | 0 | 0 |
| Piercing I | 3 | 2 |
| Piercing II | 23 | 12 |
| Piercing III | 43 | 22 |
| Piercing IV | 63 | 32 |
| Power I | 0 | 0 |
| Power II | 12 | 6 |
| Power III | 24 | 12 |
| Power IV | 35 | 18 |
| Power V | 47 | 24 |
| Projectile Protection I | 3 | 2 |
| Projectile Protection II | 10 | 5 |
| Projectile Protection III | 17 | 9 |
| Projectile Protection IV | 24 | 12 |
| Protection I | 0 | 0 |
| Protection II | 13 | 7 |
| Protection III | 26 | 13 |
| Protection IV | 39 | 20 |
| Punch I | 13 | 7 |
| Punch II | 37 | 19 |
| Quick Charge I | 17 | 9 |
| Quick Charge II | 27 | 14 |
| Quick Charge III | 38 | 19 |
| Respiration I | 11 | 6 |
| Respiration II | 23 | 12 |
| Respiration III | 34 | 17 |
| Riptide I | 19 | 10 |
| Riptide II | 31 | 16 |
| Riptide III | 43 | 22 |
| Sharpness I | 0 | 0 |
| Sharpness II | 13 | 7 |
| Sharpness III | 26 | 13 |
| Sharpness IV | 39 | 20 |
| Sharpness V | 52 | 26 |
| Silk Touch I | 17 | 9 |
| Smite I | 5 | 3 |
| Smite II | 14 | 7 |
| Smite III | 24 | 12 |
| Smite IV | 33 | 17 |
| Smite V | 43 | 22 |
| Sweeping Edge I | 5 | 3 |
| Sweeping Edge II | 15 | 8 |
| Sweeping Edge III | 26 | 13 |
| Thorns I | 11 | 6 |
| Thorns II | 34 | 17 |
| Thorns III | 58 | 29 |
| Unbreaking I | 5 | 3 |
| Unbreaking II | 14 | 7 |
| Unbreaking III | 24 | 12 |

[Original gist predating tables in StackExchange](https://gist.github.com/cherryblossom000/a81504107c3c6797f43621c37a5e855f)

Comment: Very confusing, i was asking for how many bookshelves and experience levels is used for EVERY enchantment and enchantment level

Comment: @Theleagueofunknowngamers That's how the game works. You can figure out the number of bookshelves and XP levels using this information.

Comment: could you please tell me how? It's barely any numbers and only 2 enchantments even mentioned and 1 time.bookshelves are mentioned

Comment: I mean numbers that are understandable as to what they stand for which is none

Comment: @Theleagueofunknowngamers I updated my answer to explain how to calculate it.

Comment: Very confusing, like where did the 65 even come from? As well as the .85 and 18, also, wdym by "enchantability" "modifying" i'm not modifying anything other than the tool by enchanting it

Comment: (Nvm about the .85, but how do you know it's .85 and not .96 or 1.15 or ect.?)

Comment: @Theleagueofunknowngamers I used 0.85 as it’s he worst case scenario. That way it would guarantee that you have a chance of getting the enchantment.

Comment: Wdym worst case scenario anyways?

Comment: @Theleagueofunknowngamers The game chooses a number between 0.85 and 1.15 to multiply the level by. To guarantee that you have a chance of getting the enchantment no matter what this number will be, you use 0.85 in the calculations.

Comment: So the "modified enchantment level" is how much xp it costs when combining via anvil? Can u just give me how to do the math "y = kx +m" if k and m depend on the '"type of enchantment" then what does it mean by that

Comment: @Theleagueofunknowngamers Anvil costs are different and are described in detail [on the wiki](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Anvil_mechanics). The formula for the number of levels, l, is `l = x ÷ 0.85 - 1`. The formula for the number of bookshelves, b, is `b = floor((x ÷ 0.85 - 1) ÷ 2)`, where floor means to round down to the nearest integer. x in both formulas is the lower value of the modified enchantment level for the enchantment (found [here]https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Enchanting/Levels)).

Comment: I have been to that site b4 and the math usn't explained thoroughly, i needed the math for the stuff with the crossbow (so i could fix my most likely incorrect numbers 4 the crossbow) i am currently in algebra 1 B and so yeah.......i am a sophomore in high school

Comment: @Theleagueofunknowngamers That page says, "The minimum values are all calculated using a linear function y = kx+m where […] k and m varies between different enchantments. The maximum values are all the minimum values plus a constant that varies for each enchantment." I don't know the value of k, m, or the constant because they vary for each enchantment.

Comment: Yeah "depending on the enchantment" how do you know the values of k and M just by looking at the name of the enchantment,? You can't just look at the enchantment name and be like "oh looting, k and m = 1" that's litterally and physically, AND metaphorically impossible to do...

Comment: @Theleagueofunknowngamers I don’t know how they obtained those values, but I know the modified enchantment levels because it’s on the official wiki.

Comment: Ik i looked there a while ago I also only noticed the gist yesterday